# I've write a code and I'm getting error while using matplotlib in the editor I am getting invalid syntax error, does anyone know why?

Tags: python, matplotlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import time as t

times = []
mistake = 0

print("you will have to type the word 'programming' as fast as you can for five times")

input("Press Enter to Continue.")

while len(times) < 5

```
start = t.time()

word = input("Type the Word: ")

end = t.time()

time_elapsed = end - start

times.append(time_elapsed)

if(word.lower()! = "programming"):

   mistake += 1
```

print("You made" + str(mistake) + "mistakes.")

print("Now let's See your evolution")

t.sleep(3)

x = [1,2,3,4,5]

y = times

plt.plot(x,y)

legend = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

plt.xticks(x,legend)

plt.ylabel("Time in Seconds")

plt.xlabel("Attempts")

plt.title("Your Typing Evolution")

plt.show()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want to get any help - please add error message, format your code properly and change the title. Read this: [How to ask question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem was with the indentation and syntax. After these errors removed, your code is working fine. The code without any errors is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time as t

times = []
mistake = 0
print("you will have to type the word 'programming' as fast as you can for five times")
input("Press Enter to Continue.")

while len(times) < 5:
    start = t.time()
    word = input("Type the Word: ")
    end = t.time()
    time_elapsed = end - start
    times.append(time_elapsed)
    if word.lower() != "programming":
        mistake += 1

print("You made" + str(mistake) + "mistakes.")
print("Now let's See your evolution")
t.sleep(3)
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = times
plt.plot(x,y)
legend = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
plt.xticks(x,legend)
plt.ylabel("Time in Seconds")
plt.xlabel("Attempts")
plt.title("Your Typing Evolution")
plt.show()
```